# How to do multiple column conversions on a Pandas Row in a DF in one pass

Tags: python, pandas

So I have  a Pandas DF with many date fields that need to be datetime so I have the following working but know that it is lousy Python, at minimum it cycles the entire DF once per field, and the df is 410,000 rows.

```
table.index=pd.to_datetime(table.index) #not sure why it does not come in as datetime?
table['STATUS_DATE']=pd.to_datetime(table['STATUS_DATE'])
table['DATE_MODIFIED']=pd.to_datetime(table['DATE_MODIFIED'])
table['SOLD_DATE']=pd.to_datetime(table['SOLD_DATE'])
table['WITHDRAWN_DATE']=pd.to_datetime(table['WITHDRAWN_DATE'])
table['END_DATE']=table[['DATE_MODIFIED', 'STATUS_DATE','SOLD_DATE','WITHDRAWN_DATE']].min(axis=1)
table['SUBDIVISION'].replace(df3['NSUBDIVISION'],inplace=True)
table['CALC_DOM']=table.index # there should be a single line version???
table['CALC_DOM']=table['END_DATE']-table['CALC_DOM']
```

I'd like to loop the df once and convert all the fields? Suggestions welcome I'm just beginning to be able to write some of this stuff but want to learn to do it right rather than the ugly stuff I have above.

Comment: are you reading from a csv? all of this can be done upon reading.... (use ``parse_dates = list_of_fields``)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see my comment above, but you could do:

```
In [5]: df = DataFrame(randn(10,1))

In [6]: df['col1'] = '20130101'

In [7]: df['col2'] = '20130102 9:01'

In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
          0      col1           col2
0 -1.111980  20130101  20130102 9:01
1  1.417732  20130101  20130102 9:01
2 -0.111606  20130101  20130102 9:01
3 -0.999599  20130101  20130102 9:01
4 -0.229082  20130101  20130102 9:01
5  0.535978  20130101  20130102 9:01
6 -1.913625  20130101  20130102 9:01
7  1.000879  20130101  20130102 9:01
8  0.358047  20130101  20130102 9:01
9  0.764761  20130101  20130102 9:01

In [9]: col_list = ['col1','col2']

In [10]: df[col_list] = df[col_list].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))

In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
          0                col1                col2
0 -1.111980 2013-01-01 00:00:00 2013-01-02 09:01:00
1  1.417732 2013-01-01 00:00:00 2013-01-02 09:01:00
2 -0.111606 2013-01-01 00:00:00 2013-01-02 09:01:00
3 -0.999599 2013-01-01 00:00:00 2013-01-02 09:01:00
4 -0.229082 2013-01-01 00:00:00 2013-01-02 09:01:00
5  0.535978 2013-01-01 00:00:00 2013-01-02 09:01:00
6 -1.913625 2013-01-01 00:00:00 2013-01-02 09:01:00
7  1.000879 2013-01-01 00:00:00 2013-01-02 09:01:00
8  0.358047 2013-01-01 00:00:00 2013-01-02 09:01:00
9  0.764761 2013-01-01 00:00:00 2013-01-02 09:01:00
```

Comment: Both approaches look good to me, will do the conversion on read csv most likely but the Lambda refresher is also helpful, Thank you!